# Polymer: Add and remove class (after 1 second)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `<div>` inside a Polymer template that I want to animate using CSS. I want to be able to re-trigger the animation every time a specific observer function (`onTriggered`) is called.

I've tried the following function to add and then remove the CSS class so that it can be re-triggered when the observer is called again, but it returns `Cannot read property 'myContainer' of undefined`. I understand this is due to Polymer objects not being able to be called inside Javascript functions, but I can't find an alternative solution.

```
onTriggered: function (newData, oldData) {
    if (oldData && oldData !== newData) {
        this.$.myContainer.classList.add("animated", "jello");
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.$.myContainer.classList.remove("animated", "jello");
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to synchronously add and then (after `x` seconds) remove a CSS class in a Polymer element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the scope changed in your `setTimeout` callback function. You would need to change the scope to use `this` inside the callback.

Please try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   this.$.myContainer.classList.remove("animated", "jello");
}, 1000, this);
```

or this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   this.$.myContainer.classList.remove("animated", "jello");
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! The scope was indeed the issue. Your code didn't appear to work directly, but assigning this to a variable did the track!

Comment: Just wrote it without tests :))

Answer (score 0):

As @Kejt said, the scope was indeed the issue. To solve this, I had to assign `this` to a variable, and then refer to the variable inside the `setTimeout` function, i.e.:

```
this.$.myContainer.classList.add("animated", "jello");
var polymerThis = this;
setTimeout(function() {
   polymerThis.$.myContainer.classList.remove("animated", "jello");
}, 1000);
```